# Rmarkdown/knitr captions for tables using {gtsummary}

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary

What is the best option or suggested workflow for adding captions to `gtsummary` tables in Rmarkdown documents?

For examples, I know there's a function for `kable` tables, so in theory one might convert one into the other using `gtsummary::as_kable()`, but somehow this doesn't feel optimal. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show an example with some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gt package has many many functions for controlling how a gt table prints.  I suggest you convert the gtsummary object to gt using the `as_gt()` function, then continue customizing with gt functions. https://gt.rstudio.com/ Small example included below.
[image]

```r
library(gtsummary)

mod <- glm(response ~ age + grade, trial, family = binomial)

tbl_regression(mod, exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_header("Table 1. Very Informative Model",
                 subtitle = "Highly Confidential")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, Daniel.

I just noticed a problem with superscript/subscript. As you mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534214/how-do-i-add-subscripts-to-labels-in-tables-using-the-gtsummary-package-in-r), converting to a `kable` is one option to get variable names such as `BMI (m·kg<sup>-2</sup>)`.

Comment: Sorry, messed up with the comment:

Thanks for your input, Daniel!
I'm only having one problem with this approach: HTML/Markdown variable labels are not interpreted by `gt` when piping the table to `as_gt()`. In theory, `gt` should support HTML and Markdown in cell text.

Would it be possible to make markup work in `gtsummary` cells (specifically: "row labels" in the `gt` diagram you pasted)? Or maybe I'm getting it wrong? I'm trying:

`label = list(
    bmi ~ "BMI (kg · m<sup>-2</sup>"
)`

It already seems to work when piping `gtsummary` objects to `gtsummary::modify_*` functions?

Comment: HI @MarcoB ! I can look into this further. But this seems to be a separate question from this post. Can you please post a new question with a reprex? (Use the gtsummary tag, and I'll be notified of the post.)