# using subscripts in gtsummary in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

**Context**

I am making a table and saving it into Microsoft Word with `.docx` file.

the table has a variable named `PM2.5`. I want to subscript `2.5` like PM<sub>2.5</sub>.

In [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534421/11636376), I can use the grammar `'PM~2.5~'` with `as_kable()` to use subscrpit in `PM2.5`.

But when I save the result (`tab`), it is a blank `.docx` file.

**Question**

How can I use subscripts in gtsummary and save it into `.docx` file?

**Reproducible code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
        
df = data.frame(PM2.5 = 1)

tab = # make a table using gtsummary
  df %>% 
  tbl_summary(label = PM2.5 ~ 'PM~2.5~') %>% # subscript in main table
  modify_table_styling(columns = label,
                       rows = label == 'PM~2.5~',
                       footnote = 'PM~2.5~ in footnote') %>%  # subscript in footnote
  as_kable()

tab %>% flextable::save_as_docx(path = 'test.docx') # a blank .docx file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is blank is because you're using `flextable::save_as_docx()` to save the table. That function will only work with flextables...not `knitr::kable()` tables.

You can put this table in an R markdown or Quarto document with output type Word, and the table will appear.